Is it possible to compute the function period for the given function?
I have this function
$$  f(x)= \lvert  \sin(a\,x+b\,x)\rvert -\lvert  \sin(a\,x)\rvert\;,$$
in which $\frac ab\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$. Since $a>0$ and $b>0$ are rationally related, the function is periodic with respect to $x$. In general, is it possible to compute the function period in terms of $a$ and $b$ for such a function?
I appreciate any hints or comments.

The reasonable thing to do would be to call $a=m+n$, write $f$ as $\lvert \sin(ax)\rvert-\lvert \sin (mx)\rvert$ and go from there.

Man, it's difficult for me to see $m$ and $n$ and not think of them as being integers.

@JonathanZ No, only their ratio is rational. I changed them to $a$ and $b$ :)

BTW, I think if you do write $a/b$ as a ratio of integers (with no common divisors), the answer is likely to be the least common multiple of those integers.

The period of $\lvert \sin x\rvert$ is $\pi.$
The period of $\lvert \sin (ax)\rvert$ is $\frac\pi a.$
Let $c = a + b;$ then the period of $\lvert \sin (cx)\rvert$ is $\frac\pi c.$
Now you have two periodic functions with known periods, and you can deduce a number that is certain to be a period of their difference.
The only remaining question is whether it is possible for one function to cancel the other in a way that allows a shorter period.

Thanks. But the main problem is finding the period of the difference. As I check numerically, I cannot get a precise answer for the smallest common multiple of the two periods.

I did not find that step to be difficult. Perhaps you should edit the question to show your attempts so that people can give you guidance on how to do it better.

On further consideration, it matters how you describe your numbers. When you are dealing with non-integers, LCM or GCD calculations usually need to be done symbolically. If you try to do them numerically, you are likely to run afoul of the fact that your numeric representations are inexact.

HINT FOR THE INITIAL STEP.-When $\sin(ax)\ge0$ you have $f(x)=|\sin(ax+bx)-\sin(ax)|$ and when $\sin(ax)\lt0$ you have $f(x)=|\sin(ax+bx)+\sin(ax)|$. Transformig this you have two functions to compute under the sign of absolute value in which you can proceed in the standard way:
$$f(x)=\left|2\cos\left(\frac{2ax+bx}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac {bx}{2}\right)\right|\\f(x)=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{2ax+bx}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {bx}{2}\right)\right|$$

You should get $|\sin(bx/2)|$ and $|\cos(bx/2)|$ at the last two formulas.

@Ryszard Szwarc: Obviously it was a tipe. Thank you very much.

First, I would split $f(x)$ into two separate functions:
$f_1(x)=|\sin(ax+bx)|\\
f_2(x)=-|\sin(ax)|$
Since the original function is the sum of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, we can calculate its period by first finding the periods of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, then locating the first common point where the endpoints of both periods coincide.

$f_1(x)$ can be rewritten as $|\sin((a+b)x)|$, so its period $p_1=\frac{\pi}{(a+b)}$.
$f_2(x)$ has a period $p_2=\frac{\pi}{a}$.

For the next step, we can use the ratio $\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ to see how many times $p_1$ can fit into $p_2$ (and since $a>0$ and $b>0$, we know that $p_2>p_1$, which means $\frac{p_2}{p_1}>1$). If $\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ turns out to be a whole number, then we know that a whole number of $p_1$s fit into $p_2$, which means their endpoints coincide at the end of $p_2$, determining that the period of $f(x)$ is $p_2$. In most cases however, $\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ will probably be a repeating/terminating decimal that we can convert to an improper fraction. The point of all this is to figure out the smallest whole number of $p_2$s that also contain a whole number of $p_1$s. In other words, we need to find the smallest whole number $c$ where $\frac{p_2 \cdot c}{p_1}$ is also a whole number, and this tells us that $p_2 \cdot c$ is the period required for the endpoints of $p_1$ and $p_2$ to coincide, meaning the period of $f(x)$ is $p_2 \cdot c$.
Now, how do we find $c$? After converting $\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ to an improper fraction, we need to make sure it is reduced to its lowest terms. Then, we know that $c$ is simply equal to the denominator of the reduced fraction.
Here's an example to illustrate this method. Let's take $a=1.2$ and $b=0.8$, which makes $p_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $p_2=\frac{5\pi}{6}$. Then, $\frac{p_2}{p_1}=1.\overline{6}$, which can be converted to $\frac53$ (this means that $p_2$ contains exactly $\frac53$ $p_1$s). Since $\frac53$ is already in the lowest terms, we know that $c=3$ , so the period of $f(x)$ is $\frac{5\pi}{6} \cdot 3=\frac{5\pi}{2}$ (in context, this means that it takes a minimum of three $p_2$s to contain a whole number of $p_1$s, allowing the endpoints of $p_1$ and $p_2$ coincide). You can also check by graphing the functions and observing the behavior of $f(x)$ at $x=\frac{5\pi}{2}$.
